Is there a way to apply geopandas function to all rows except for those that raise an error?
I am trying to apply a buffer to a geodataframe of 600,000 rows (as part of a larger process), the gdf contains linestrings and multi-linestrings for geometry. When I run the buffer code line:
gdf['buffer_geometry'] = gdf.buffer(305)

I recieve the following error:

GEOSException: TopologyException: assigned depths do not match at -12250000 3700000

I iterated through the geodataframe and found out that this error is raised on 2 non-consecutive rows (index 4934 and index 80,023).
I do not care about having a buffer calculated for these two rows - instead I want to set up logic in my code to compute the buffer for all rows except for those two which raise the error, and return None in those two rows.
I know that this is against the grain of how pandas is designed to work - but is there a way to accomplish this without iterating over each row individually? I need to prioritize having most of the rows run successfully and quickly, over having every single row populated with a buffer.
Below is a row by row loop that I wrote to illustrate what I would like to achieve, but it is way to slow for my needs.
# To stop the loop
max = len(gdf)

# Indices
start = 0
end = 1

failed_index = []
while start <= max:
    GDF_copy = GDF.copy()
    GDF_copy = GDF_copy[start:end]

    # Try to return buffer geometry
    try:
        buffer = GDF_copy['line_geom'].buffer(305)
        GDF.loc[start, ['buffer_geom']] = buffer

    # If buffer function fails, return None
    except:
        GDF.loc[start, ['buffer_geom']] = None
        failed_index.append(start)
    
    start += 1
    end += 1


Are all the geometries valid df.geometry.is_valid.all()? If not make them valid df.geometry.make_valid()and try buffering

Using apply method with a lambda function should work and it avoids the loop over each row :
# Function to apply buffer and handle errors
def no_error_buffer(geometry, distance):
    try:
        return geometry.buffer(distance)
    except:
        return None

# Apply the buffer with the function to handle exceptions
gdf['buffer_geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda geom: no_error_buffer(geom, 305))


Thank you for your response - unfortunately this is moving slower than the loop for me. Happy to hear any recs you would have on speeding up this process.

You can try using parallel processing with joblib's Parallel and delayed : buffered_geometries = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(no_error_buffer)(geom, 305) for geom in gdf['geometry']) and then gdf['buffer_geometry'] = buffered_geometries. The n_jobs=-1 ensures you use all available ressources.

List comprehension is typically quite fast.
[edit] but for me, apply is the same performance as list comprehension, so also quite fast?
For a testfile with 30.000 polygons:

using just the standard gdf.geometry.buffer(305) took 4.9 seconds
your loop took 56 seconds
list comprehension took 5.7 seconds
[edit]: using apply also takes 5.7 seconds?

Code sample:
def try_buffer(geometry, distance):
    try:
        return geometry.buffer(distance)
    except:
        return None

gdf.geometry = [try_buffer(g, 305) for g in gdf.geometry]

